# Issue with Error handling on Firebase remove function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The promise that is returned by `userRef.remove()` is not giving any error, it always goes to then block even though if I change the non existing path  `dbRef.child('userssafasfsadf/' + userID);` like so.

```
function deleteButtonClicked(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    var userID = e.target.getAttribute("userid");

    const userRef = dbRef.child('users/' + userID);

    userRef.remove()

       .then(() => { 
           console.log('success!, show alert now'); 
       }) 
       .catch(err => { 
           console.log('errorcode', err.code); 
       });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Could not get catch block even though there is an error.

Comment: I can't seem to find a list of possible errors remove() can throw. My guess is that an invalid path doesn't cause an error (except when you dont have write authority) so maybe its better to ask for all the possible errors this function can generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're expecting the remove() function to generate an error if there was no data at the given location.  It doesn't work that way, because the remove() is not transactional. Someone else could have removed the data a split second ahead of you, and that's OK.  Database operations only return errors when a security rule is violated.